# Scaling View / Changing Resolution - SWIFT4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to make buttons bigger on the iPad rather than using the extra space from the bigger screen. Of course I can check the screen width and then adjust all the sizes, but is there another way I can apply to an existing app without going through thousands of line of code?

Is there a way to let iOS think the iPad width is only half as big or only 75% of what it really is and therefore show everything bigger?

I would have to do this at the beginning of `viewdidLoad` because there is lots of code depending on screen size.

Comment: How about setting the button size conditionally on the size class? Only an iPad is Regular / Regular.

Comment: that would work for the buttons, but I also wan to make the fonts bigger, separation lines, paddings, etc etc etc.